# Why are certain ship modules listed as upgrades on the ship sheets?

Tags: scum-and-villainy

To give a specific example; on the ship sheet for the Cerberus, under Weapons Systems, the ship begins with a grappling hook module. Under that is listed 'particle cannons' as a possible upgrade, then a blank upgrade option. The rules in the book for upgrading modules (pages 51 & 118) seem clear enough, and infer that any module may be chosen.

So why are particle cannons specifically listed on the ship sheet? Is it just a suggestion as to the best choice, or is there some mechanical advantage to choosing this upgrade over another module?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

John LeBoeuf-Little, co-author of the game.

What you're talking about are 'available modules' and their purpose is to make clear what systems are easily found and installed for ships of that type. While nearly any module can be fit into any ship (any cable rerouting is easily accomplished, no matter the system or ship) some modules are easier to source.

Mechanically, this means that, when you advance your crew and gain upgrades, you may freely spend them on these available modules. Getting Afterburners installed into the Stardancer is a trivial affair. We can handle that off-screen. But getting any sort of weapon installed on the ship will take a bit of explaining - a downtime action, a job, or often free play with some of your contacts.

As a GM, how strict you are about the availability of modules is up to you, and says things about the world. I like to use fortune rolls using the Tech or Crime/Syndicate ratings of the planet in question. Regardless, available modules should always be easily available - that's what that term means.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, that answer nearly makes sense but then I'm confused about the starting condition of the Cerberus. It starts with two Comms improvements (is that the right word?) but hasn't installed a Nexus Link. If installing is simple enough to handle offscreen, why wouldn't it be installed by default on this ship?

Comment: @sparker The Cerberus starts with a _quality rating_ of 2 in comms, and one comms module (long range scanner) installed. You could install any second comm module you can get your grubs on, but at that point you've run out of room in comms (p118). Nexus Link isn't installed by default; you'd have to spend a pick to get it. In contrast, Fake Transponder is a comms module, but you'd _also_ need to acquire it in fiction.

Comment: At the start of a new campaign, why _wouldn't_ someone just say "We install the Nexus Link offscreen" if that's the case? Are they supposed to be hard to remove?